# How do I go about replicating the "opened/unopened" system of your phones "mail" app in a NodeJS + MongoDB application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design

The app we are dealing with:

- Imagine a NodeJS e-commerce app where you can purchase items, and user orders are stored in MongoDB.
- Imagine the app has an admin dashboard where all orders are listed in a table.

So far so good, this part I have already taken care off!

However, I also want an easy way to see which orders are new and have not been "opened" yet. This would function similarly to your "mail" app on your phone where new mails which you haven't opened yet are styled differently so you can see they are new.

One may think you can simply add a "opened: true/false" field to the order object, but it is not so simple. I want the "opened/unopened" state to be individual for each admin on the app meaning that if admin_1 opens the order, it should be "opened" for him, however, still "unopened" for admin_2.

I was thinking about something like an array of all admins with a "opened: true/false" field on the orders but this seems like a horrible idea as the number of admins can become large and it doesn't handle new or deleted admins. All other approaches I can think of has similar issues, or they end up leading to a ridiculous amount of data being stored.

Therefore, I am asking, how could I go about implementing the system I described without needing to double or triple my database size?

Comment: Create a junction table between admins and orders.  Write a row to the junction table when an order is opened.  If there's no row in the junction table, the order is unopened.  You can delete the rows in the junction table when the order is fulfilled or closed.